# Where is the scriptural reference (or evidence) that the Bhagavad Gita is an Upanishad?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, upanishads, reference-request

Some people say the Bhagavad Gita to be an Upanishad like Srila Prabhupada in his introduction to the Bhagavad Gita styling it as Gitopanisad. So do any scriptures say the Bhagavad Gita to be an Upanishad?
Note: I am looking for scriptural references only

Answer (score 0):

Gita itself claims to be an Upanishad at the end of every chapter.

[image]

Reply to the Comment down below:

I checked Radhakrishnan after reading the comment.

> This is the usual colophon which is not a part of the text.

**Remarks by S. Radhakrishnan in his English translation of the Gita**

Comment: But is it really part of the original Bhagavad Gita that we find in the Mahabharata?

Comment: No it is not part of the Text according to Radhakrishnan. It is a colophon.

Comment: so who added it and is it really a scriptural reference?

Comment: I don't know. It may not be scriptural reference but it would not have survived if Gita was not regarded as equivalent to the Upanishads.